# How to keep temp table in below query in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
select Executive, count([Cat A]) AS [1-3], count([Cat B]) AS [4-6],count([Cat C]) AS [7-10],count([Cat D]) AS [11-15],count([Cat E]) AS [16+]
      from (
            select 
                  Executive,
                case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 0 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 4)
                              then 'A'
                  end as [Cat A],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 3 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 7)
                              then 'B'
                  end as [Cat B],
                  case when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 6 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 11)
                              then 'C'
                  end as [Cat C],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 10 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 16)
                              then 'D'
                  end as [Cat D],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 15)
                              then 'E'
                  end as [Cat E]
                  from vw_FollowUps)
            as Table1
      group by Executive, [Cat A], [Cat B], [Cat C], [Cat D], [Cat E]
```

---

**output is coming like below**

```
Executive  1-3  4-6  7-10  11-15  16+

Rani       0    0     0     0     0
Rani       0    1     0     2     0
Rani       0    0     1     0     0
```

---

**but i need like this below output**

```
Executive  1-3  4-6  7-10  11-15  16+

Rani        0    1     1     2     0
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Add a select around the entire thing:

```
SELECT Executive  SUM([1-3]), SUM([4-6]), SUM([7-10]), SUM([11-15]), SUM([16+])
FROM
(

   ....YOUR BIG SELECT....
)
GROUP BY Executive
```

So like this:

```
SELECT Executive  SUM([1-3]), SUM([4-6]), SUM([7-10]), SUM([11-15]), SUM([16+])
FROM
(

    select Executive, count([Cat A]) AS [1-3], count([Cat B]) AS [4-6],count([Cat C]) AS [7-10],count([Cat D]) AS [11-15],count([Cat E]) AS [16+]
      from (
            select 
                  Executive,
                case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 0 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 4)
                              then 'A'
                  end as [Cat A],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 3 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 7)
                              then 'B'
                  end as [Cat B],
                  case when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 6 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 11)
                              then 'C'
                  end as [Cat C],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 10 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 16)
                              then 'D'
                  end as [Cat D],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 15)
                              then 'E'
                  end as [Cat E]
                  from vw_FollowUps)
            as Table1
      group by Executive, [Cat A], [Cat B], [Cat C], [Cat D], [Cat E]

)
GROUP BY Executive
```

Answer (score 2):

An additional SELECT (the other two answers) is **extraneous**.

Simple GROUP BY *only* the `Executive` column.

```
select Executive, count([Cat A]) AS [1-3], count([Cat B]) AS [4-6],count([Cat C]) AS [7-10],count([Cat D]) AS [11-15],count([Cat E]) AS [16+]
      from (
            select 
                  Executive,
                case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 0 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 4)
                              then 'A'
                  end as [Cat A],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 3 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 7)
                              then 'B'
                  end as [Cat B],
                  case when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 6 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 11)
                              then 'C'
                  end as [Cat C],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 10 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 16)
                              then 'D'
                  end as [Cat D],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 15)
                              then 'E'
                  end as [Cat E]
                  from vw_FollowUps)
            as Table1
      group by Executive;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Common Table Expression(CTE)` to get above result...You can have new query with CTE as following:(Not tested but the way of implementation is right)

```
WITH CTETABLE AS 
(
select Executive, count([Cat A]) AS [1-3], count([Cat B]) AS [4-6],count([Cat C]) AS [7-10],count([Cat D]) AS [11-15],count([Cat E]) AS [16+]
      from (
            select 
                  Executive,
                case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 0 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 4)
                              then 'A'
                  end as [Cat A],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 3 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 7)
                              then 'B'
                  end as [Cat B],
                  case when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 6 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 11)
                              then 'C'
                  end as [Cat C],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 10 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 16)
                              then 'D'
                  end as [Cat D],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 15)
                              then 'E'
                  end as [Cat E]
                  from vw_FollowUps)
            as Table1
      group by Executive, [Cat A], [Cat B], [Cat C], [Cat D], [Cat E]
)
SELECT Executive, MAX([1-3]),MAX([4-6]),MAX([7-10]),MAX([11-15],MAX([16+]) FROM CTETABLE GROUP BY Executive;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  Executive, SUM([1-3]), SUM([4-6]), SUM([7-10]), SUM([11-15]), SUM([16+]) FROM
(
select Executive, count([Cat A]) AS [1-3], count([Cat B]) AS [4-6],count([Cat C]) AS [7-10],count([Cat D]) AS [11-15],count([Cat E]) AS [16+]
      from (
            select 
                  Executive,
                case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 0 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 4)
                              then 'A'
                  end as [Cat A],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 3 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 7)
                              then 'B'
                  end as [Cat B],
                  case when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 6 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 11)
                              then 'C'
                  end as [Cat C],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 10 and DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) < 16)
                              then 'D'
                  end as [Cat D],
                  case  when [Next Follow Up Date] < GETDATE() and (DATEDIFF(d,[next follow up date],getdate()) > 15)
                              then 'E'
                  end as [Cat E]
                  from vw_FollowUps)
            as Table1
      group by Executive, [Cat A], [Cat B], [Cat C], [Cat D], [Cat E] ) AS T
group by Executive
```